# Admob banner works in expo but not testflight

Tags: react-native, admob, expo, react-native-ios

I have an admob banner in my react native app which works perfectly in the expo client and ios simulator, but on testflight the ad doesn't load and I get this error

```
Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDeion=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

Here's the code for the admob banner

```
import { AdMobBanner } from "expo-ads-admob";
...
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="banner"
  adUnitID={this.adUnitID}
  servePersonalizedAds={false}
/>
```

When I use google's demo adUnitId `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716` the ad loads on testflight, but not with my own adUnitId. According to other stackoverflow questions, if this is the case, the add should work on testFlight after 4 days once google has approved the ad. However, it's been nearly 2 weeks and it still isn't working. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to billing your account and check the adUnitID again.

Comment: I can't set up billing until I make a payment threshold of $100 and I can't receive payment until the ad works

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 similar IDs for Admob, **googleMobileAdsAppId** and **adUnitID**.

> **googleMobileAdsAppId** is like 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx'
> which should be in app.json file.
> **adUnitID** is like 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx' which should be inside
> <¥AdMobBanner>

Do you refer to the right ID?